# How to create password encrypted backup with gpg

Tags: backup, encryption, gpg

Recently, I made a script that archives important files with [gzip](https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/),
encrypts them with [gpg](https://www.gnupg.org/), using
`gpg --symmetric`
(which prompts me for a password), then
uploads it.

I was testing the backup on another PC, but cannot decrypt it, even when I supplied the correct password (copy&  pasted from password manager). There was an error about half a second after and it failed with an invalid packet error.

How can I encrypt that file, so anyone with the proper password can decrypt it? I don't want to share keyrings as I've read elsewhere unless absolutely necessary, as it's another thing I need to think of and distribute and sync between my machines, including future ones. I would like to decrypt it with just a password.

Comment: The command is correct. Encrypt with: `gpg --symmetric filename`, decrypt with `gpg --decrypt filename.gpg`. What does your script look like? What command do you use to decrypt it?

Comment: What was the exact error? It sounds like the password was correct, but something else went wrong? If you don't specify a good `--cipher-algo` or use `--force-mdc` you might default to not having any modification detection code. Are you sure the file was transferred unchanged? And +1 to DeathkampDrone's comments too

Comment: Okay, I was able to decrypt it and I can access the files, but I'm not sure if the backup is complete. While decrypting: 

     "gpg: problem reading source (xxx bytes remaining)
     gpg: handle plaintext failed: No such file or directory
     gpg: decryption failed: Invalid packet". I'll verify if hash of the uploaded/downloaded file matches. I didn't specify any of these options, it defaulted to AES. Cc @Deathkamp Drone : I used the commands that you wrote.